While using thirdweb, How to make a writefunction call when the contract is not verified without passing the private key
So while using the thirdweb,
i have a contract on loop mainnet, and is not verifiable, but i have the abi of that contract.
now
const network = Loopnetwork;
const privateKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_KEY;
const sdk = ThirdwebSDK.fromPrivateKey(privateKey, network);

works fine and i get an sdk, but it is with my account's private key, and i am able to create a contract instance as follows
const contract = await sdk.getContractFromAbi(Contract_ADDRESS, Contract_ABI);

and with that i am able to call any read/write function with it, e.g
const { mutateAsync: approve } = useContractWrite(contract, "approve");

but what it does is that it uses my wallet account in the background without popping up the metamask.
But if i want this function to be called by someone eles's account, that is not possible since metamask is not popped up and the private key is passed so it performs functions against it.
If i don't pass the privatekey in the sdk, then it gives error and doesnt go forward. So i want a workaround or solution, if anyone can help, since my whole project is configured on thirdweb and i can't use the useContractWrite() hook since my contract is not verified.
